# Controlling the camera flash on the Galaxy Nexus and Note from within a service

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm wanting to control the camera led on the Galaxy Nexus and Note.
I've managed to control it using the open source app search-light here: http://code.google.com/p/search-light/

My only issue is that I'm wanting to control flashing the LED from a service and not from within an activity and it seems the way they get it working is by using SurfaceView and rendering one visible dot onto the screen.

I don't mind starting an activity if needed as long as there's some way to stop it from interfeering with what's currently active on the screen.

Any suggestions?
Thanks